# With iOS13, is there now an easy way to change the language of an app on the fly?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, ios13

I know that similar questions were asked before but with **iOS 13**, Apple has given all users the option to change the language of an app via settings (iPhone Settings -> e.g. Chrome -> Language).

Is there now an API or similar in iOS 13 that we can use to change the language of an app right from within the app? - I want to let users change the language directly rather than sending them to the iPhone settings.

Comment: Then you will need to do it inside your app cretaing a settings panel and chosing the language, and ofc use localisation.

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha Thanks for your answer! But what is the right way of setting the app's language then? Did Apple introduce a new API for that in iOS 13?

Comment: Try this maybe? https://medium.com/swift2go/forcing-ios-localization-at-runtime-the-right-way-8afa0569162a

Comment: Thanks for the hint @GregdeJ but unfortunately this doesn't work completely as the author states at the end: "Sadly, Localized Info.plist ignores runtime language set, and so far I was not able to resolve this issue." Most of my translations are in the Info.plist, so this will not work for me.